# Absolute position element disabling functionality of elements behind it

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have a users list in which when I click on a user, a chat-box opens ( https://github.com/irontec/angular-bootstrap-simple-chat ). I set the chat-box `position: absolute`. The problem is that this chat-box disables everything behind it, like buttons don't click anymore [even when chat-box is closed (not visible)].

I tried playing with `z-index`, but no luck, because when I make this chat-box appear behind other element, then the buttons in this chat-box loses functionality. Has anyone had such an experience with absolute position elements?

### HTML:

```
<div class="chat-box">
    <irontec-simple-chat
            messages="MainViewVM.messages"
            username="MainViewVM.username"
            input-placeholder-text="You can write here"
            submit-button-text="{{MainViewVM.submitButtonText}}"
            title="{{MainViewVM.title}}"
            theme="material"
            submit-function="MainViewVM.sendMessage"
            visible="MainViewVM.visible"
            expand-on-new="{{MainViewVM.expandOnNew}}">
    </irontec-simple-chat>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.chat-box
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    bottom: 120px;
    right: 260px;
}
```

[plnkr.co/edit/ppaA1NvnL2vPxvI3teVr?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/ppaA1NvnL2vPxvI3teVr?p=preview)

Comment: I don't have a clear understanding of what's causing the problem, but the first thing that comes to mind as a possible solution is the CSS [**`pointer-events`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property, which enables users to click through an element to interact with elements beneath.

Comment: i did see pointer-events while searching for solution, but i dont need to click something while something else is visible on any button, I simply need normal behavior that when i show an element (chat-box) it appears but should not make elements behind it inactive.

Comment: Can you replicate it in Plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ppaA1NvnL2vPxvI3teVr?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button `Open chat` changes the display of chat-window, not chat-box. The container chat-box remains presents, visible but transparent (!).
One simple solution is to hide the container `chat-box`and to force its contents to visible. It'll works and has no conflict with angular code since angular is playing with display, not visibility.

```
.chat-box {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  bottom: 120px;
  right: 260px;
}
.chat-window {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I solved it simply by replacing "chat-box" class with "chat-window".

Answer (score 0):

Got the hint from answer by Joël Hecht for the mistake I was making.

Simply removed the custom class "chat-box" and used the directive's own class "chat-window".

### HTML:

```
<irontec-simple-chat
        messages="MainViewVM.messages"
        username="MainViewVM.username"
        input-placeholder-text="You can write here"
        submit-button-text="{{MainViewVM.submitButtonText}}"
        title="{{MainViewVM.title}}"
        theme="material"
        submit-function="MainViewVM.sendMessage"
        visible="MainViewVM.visible"
        expand-on-new="{{MainViewVM.expandOnNew}}">
</irontec-simple-chat>
```

### CSS:

```
.chat-window
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
}
```

### Working Plinker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ppaA1NvnL2vPxvI3teVr?p=preview